# How can I add "editable cell" for grouped columns in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

[Here is the code sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-surf-txj1i).

Even though i have added "Building" column cells as `editable : true`
i am not able to get the editable option as like for `name` column row cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it's mapping over the columns to check for the `editable` flag only on the top level columns, not in the `children` array where the data for the child columns is stored.  You'd need to alter the map function to check the children and replace their `onCell` property accordingly. You can try replacing:

```
const columns = this.columns.map(col => {
      if (!col.editable) {
        return col;
      }
      return {
        ...col,
        onCell: record => ({
          record,
          editable: col.editable,
          dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
          title: col.title,
          handleSave: this.handleSave,
        }),
      };
    });
```

With its own function and applying it to the children recursively.

```
const mapColumns = col => {
      if (!col.editable) {
        return col;
      }
      const newCol = {
        ...col,
        onCell: record => ({
          record,
          editable: col.editable,
          dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
          title: col.title,
          handleSave: this.handleSave
        })
      };
      if (col.children) {
        newCol.children = col.children.map(mapColumns);
      }
      return newCol;
    };

    const columns = this.columns.map(mapColumns);
```

Fork [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-shaw-kb6hh).

Comment: Your sample "codesandbox" not working now, could you please update?

Comment: [Павел](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14782021/Павел) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65188383/12695027) saying "I did another [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-editable-cells-nested-headings-2jfyq), it works now. Chris B. thanks a lot!"